# Power BI compute previous value

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have two tables in PowerBI:

First table: `type` - mark product,
`date`- the date on which the number of stocks - `state`

| type | date | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14C | 18.02.2022 | 450 |
| 11A | 20.02.2022 | 5 |
| 14C | 22.02.2022 | 440 |
| 11A | 23.02.2022 | 4 |
| 14C | 24.02.2022 | 439 |
| 8D | 26.02.2022 | 14 |
| 8D | 26.02.2022 | 114 |

Second table: a table indicating the increase or decrease in the number of the `state` (a minus sign `-`  indicates `increase`,otherwise, positive values indicate a decrease)

| type | date | in_decrese_state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14C | 21.02.2022 | 10 |
| 11A | 22.02.2022 | 1 |
| 14C | 23.02.2022 | 1 |
| 8D | 1.03.2022 | -100 |

Procedure for type 14C for example:

Initial Condition is 450(18.02.2022). Then in second table is row for this type with value 10 - it means 450 - 10 = 440. And this value is state for this type in next day(in table one) etc.

I would like to make a calculation from these two tables so that it counts as I showed. I can't handle it. Can anyone give me any advice? I tried to join the table and solve it at the SQL level, but I also couldn't.

Comment: Do these tables look exactly like what you've shown? I mean you already have the values of state calculated. It looks like you want to incrementally load table 1.

Comment: @intruderr The original state of the tables is a little different. But I'm able to sql queries just get this look.